# How to run the azure devops build completely even with failing react test cases

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs, azure-pipelines, react-typescript, azure-pipelines-yaml

How to run the azure devops build completely even if there are some failing test cases. With the below mentioned scripts, the build is exiting with error code 1.

azure build pipleline tasks:

```
   - script: "yarn --cwd frontend/ coverage"
        enabled: true
        displayName: "Run React Code coverage"
```

Package.json

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
"coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
```

Comment: If there are failing test cases, why *shouldn't* the build exit with a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Hi @HemaS, I noticed that `@jessehouwing` has shared some good suggestions in his answer. Please try using `continueOnError: true` on your test step. If the suggestions can help you solve the problem, I recommend that you can mark his answer as the solution of this topic. This may be very helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `continueOnError: true` to the script step to ignore its failure.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#script):

```yaml
steps:
- script: string  # contents of the script to run
  displayName: string  # friendly name displayed in the UI
  name: string  # identifier for this step (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  workingDirectory: string  # initial working directory for the step
  failOnStderr: boolean  # if the script writes to stderr, should that be treated as the step failing?
  condition: string
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'
  enabled: boolean  # whether to run this step; defaults to 'true'
  target:
    container: string # where this step will run; values are the container name or the word 'host'
    commands: enum  # whether to process all logging commands from this step; values are `any` (default) or `restricted`
  timeoutInMinutes: number
  env: { string: string }  # list of environment variables to add
```

**PS**: It's a bad idea to ignore test failures in CI. Instead of ignoring them, what's keeping you from fixing the issue?